# Why does @Output create circular json error?

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to catch an event emitted from my `quantity-component` 
When I take away the @Output decorator everything works fine, but when I include it to catch the event I get this error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./QuantityComponent class
>   QuantityComponent - inline template:0:567 caused by: Converting
>   circular structure to JSONErrorHandler.handleError @
>
> ...
>
> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Converting
>   circular structure to JSON

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
// item-component.ts
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'item-component',
    template: '<quantity-component [initialQuantity]="initialQuantity" (change)="myValueChange($event)" ></quantity-component>'
})
export class ItemComponent {
    myValueChange($event){
        console.log($event);
    }
}

// quantity-component.ts
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'quantity-component',
    templateUrl: 'quantity.component.html'
})
export class QuantityComponent {
    @Input() item: string;

    @Input('initialQuantity') counterValue = 0;
    @Output('change') counterChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    increase() {
        this.counterValue++;
        this.counterChange.emit({
            value: this.counterValue
        })
    }

    decrease() {
        this.counterValue--;
        this.counterChange.emit({
            value: this.counterValue
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm except that little comma in your ItemComponent template, everything is working for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5

Comment: Also failed to mention that item-component gets looped over using `*ngFor`.  Would that make a difference?

Comment: Updated the plnkr to have loop for ItemComponent, still no error: http://plnkr.co/edit/0yU6U5JVnqLxGeuVPB7G?p=preview

Comment: ItemComponent doesn't seem to have an initialQuantity property, so `[initialQuantity]="initialQuantity"` will break, but I think that's unrelated. Have you tried making `myValueChange($event){
        console.log("look at me not breaking");
    }`?